# Opening the newest file inside a specific folder

Tags: python, file-handling

I want the open a txt file.

There is a lot of .txt files in a folder on the desktop and they are always increasing.

I want to open the newest of these txt files.

```
with open(file=f"C:\\Users\\selman\Desktop\\simpleFolder\\NEWEST.txt", mode="r") as file:
```

txt file names:

```
mmnhodja_Sat Mar 12 22;00;24 2022.txt

mmnhodja_Sat Mar 12 22;02;12 2022.txt

mmnhodja_Sat Mar 12 22;04;22 2022.txt

mmnhodja_Sat Mar 12 22;06;33 2022.txt

mmnhodja_Sat Mar 12 22;08;57 2022.txt
```

going like that.

Comment: did you tried anything? is there any pattern in the file names?

Comment: I added you can see.

Comment: I did research and I always saw solutions according to the location where the os works. I couldn't find anything about finding the most recently created file inside a specific folder.

Comment: don't add images, add it like a text

Comment: You have to check the attributes of all the files in the folder to determine which is the newest. i.e. use `os.stat()`.

Comment: file name has time/date in it you can use that to get the latest created file

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How can I get the name of all the files in a particular folder? If I can reach it, I can reach the newest one by splitting the names as you said. @deadshot

Comment: you can use `pathlib` module

Comment: Likewise for os.stat() I need the names of all txt files in the folder. How can I create such a list of names?

Comment: with pathlib you can get the file names by pattern

Answer (score 2):

You can use file `stat` to find creation/modification/access time:

```
import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path


curr_dir = Path('.')
text_files = list(curr_dir.glob('*.txt'))
# sort by modification time (st_mtime) in reversed order
newest_file = sorted(
    [(f, dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(f.stat().st_mtime)) for f in text_files],
    key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True
)[0][0]
print(newest_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import os.path
import glob

os.chdir("directory") # put your Desktop directory here

files = glob.glob(directory + "*.txt") # this is to find all txt files

# If you want to find the files that were last modified
newest_files = sorted(files, key = lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x), reverse=1)

# if you want to find the files that were last created
newest_files = sorted(files, key = lambda x: os.path.getctime(x), reverse=1)
```

the `newest_files` list is a list with all files sorted from newest to oldest. If you want to also include other files then change the `"*.txt"` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import glob

os.chdir(os.getcwd())
files = sorted(glob.glob("*.txt"), key=os.path.getmtime)

print(files[-1])
```